# Serial Communication with a Serial device

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I have a blood glucose meter which supports downloading data to computer using a serial cable and its own software. I made a serial cable for this with a usb to ttl pl2303 and its working. I can download the data from the device to my pc using that software but now I want get the data to my arduino using serial communication. I have a serial monitor software which detects the communication between the device and the software usin com port.
Can any one please tell me how to get the data to my arduino?
I have attached the dump file from that serial monitor.

```
[31/08/2019 21:32:16] - Open port COM12 (C:\Program Files\Eltima Software\Serial Port Monitor\SerialMonitorx64.exe) 



[31/08/2019 21:35:10] - Open port COM12 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Diabetes_Management\Diabetes_Management_APP.exe)   

[31/08/2019 21:35:10] Written data (COM12)  
    55                                                U                 
[31/08/2019 21:35:11] - Close port COM12    

[31/08/2019 21:35:11] - Open port COM12 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Diabetes_Management\Diabetes_Management_APP.exe)   

[31/08/2019 21:35:11] Written data (COM12)  
    05                                                .                 
[31/08/2019 21:35:12] - Close port COM12    

[31/08/2019 21:35:12] - Open port COM12 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Diabetes_Management\Diabetes_Management_APP.exe)   

[31/08/2019 21:35:13] Written data (COM12)  
    05                                                .                 
[31/08/2019 21:35:13] Read data (COM12) 
    01 47 6c 75 63 6f 73 65 0d 0a 02 31 2c 32 30 31   .Glucose...1,201  
    38 2c 30 37 2c 32 30 2c 30 31 2c 30 30 2c 31 2e   8,07,20,01,00,1.  
    31 2c 6d 6d 6f 6c 5f 4c 0d 0a 32 2c 32 30 31 38   1,mmol_L..2,2018  
    2c 30 37 2c 32 30 2c 30 31 2c 30 30 2c 31 2e 31   ,07,20,01,00,1.1  
    2c 6d 6d 6f 6c 5f 4c 0d 0a 33 2c 32 30 31 38 2c   ,mmol_L..3,2018,  
    30 37 2c 32 30 2c 30 31 2c 33 37 2c 32 2e 34 2c   07,20,01,37,2.4,  
    6d 6d 6f 6c 5f 4c 0d 0a 34 2c 32 30 31 38 2c 30   mmol_L..4,2018,0  
    37 2c 32 30 2c 30 31 2c 33 36 2c 31 2e 31 2c 6d   7,20,01,36,1.1,m  
    6d 6f 6c 5f 4c 0d 0a 35 2c 32 30 31 38 2c 30 37   mol_L..5,2018,07  
    2c 32 30 2c 30 31 2c 33 35 2c 33 32 2e 37 2c 6d   ,20,01,35,32.7,m  
    6d 6f 6c 5f 4c 0d 0a 03 04                        mol_L....         
[31/08/2019 21:35:14] - Close port COM12
```

.

```
--------------------------------------
#   Time                Function                                                Dir   Status           Data                                                        Data (chars)       Data length   Req. length  Port        Comments
0   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_CREATE                                           DOWN                   C:\Program Files\Eltima Software\Serial Port Monitor\SerialMonitorx64.exe                                 COM12       
1   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_CREATE                                           UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   C:\Program Files\Eltima Software\Serial Port Monitor\SerialMonitorx64.exe                                 COM12       
2   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK)      DOWN                   19 01 00 00                                                 ....                  4                       COM12       
3   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
4   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
5   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   80 25 00 00                                                 €%..                  4                       COM12       
6   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL)   DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
7   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL)   UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   00 00 08                                                    ...                   3                       COM12       
8   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS)          DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
9   31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS)          UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   1a 00 00 1a 11 13                                           ......                6                       COM12       
10  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW)       DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
11  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW)       UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 02 00 00             ................      16                      COM12       
12  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK)       DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
13  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
14  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   80 25 00 00                                                 €%..                  4                       COM12       
15  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL)   DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
16  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL)   UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   00 00 08                                                                          3                       COM12       
17  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS)          DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
18  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS)          UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   1a 00 00 1a 11 13                                           ......                6                       COM12       
19  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW)       DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
20  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW)       UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 02 00 00             ................      16                      COM12       
21  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE)      DOWN                   00 4b 00 00                                                 .K..                  4                       COM12       
22  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
23  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS)            DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
24  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS)            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
25  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_DTR)            DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
26  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_DTR)            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
27  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL)   DOWN                   00 00 08                                                    ...                   3                       COM12       
28  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL)   UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
29  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHARS)          DOWN                   1a 00 00 1a 11 13                                           ......                6                       COM12       
30  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHARS)          UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
31  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW)       DOWN                   01 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 02 00 00             ....@...........      16                      COM12       
32  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW)       UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
33  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_MODEMSTATUS)    DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
34  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_MODEMSTATUS)    UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   f0 00 00 00                                                 ð...                  4                       COM12       
35  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS)       DOWN                   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2c 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 2c 01 00 00 ........,.......,...  20                      COM12       
36  31/08/2019 21:32:16 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS)       UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
37  31/08/2019 21:32:26 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   55                                                          U                     1           1           COM12       
38  31/08/2019 21:32:26 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   55                                                          U                     1                       COM12       
39  31/08/2019 21:32:31 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
40  31/08/2019 21:32:31 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
41  31/08/2019 21:32:35 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
42  31/08/2019 21:32:35 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
43  31/08/2019 21:32:38 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
44  31/08/2019 21:32:38 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
45  31/08/2019 21:32:44 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
46  31/08/2019 21:32:44 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
47  31/08/2019 21:33:42 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   55                                                          U                     1           1           COM12       
48  31/08/2019 21:33:42 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   55                                                          U                     1                       COM12       
49  31/08/2019 21:33:45 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
50  31/08/2019 21:33:45 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
51  31/08/2019 21:33:47 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
52  31/08/2019 21:33:47 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
53  31/08/2019 21:33:48 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
54  31/08/2019 21:33:48 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
55  31/08/2019 21:33:57 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE)      DOWN                   6e 00 00 00                                                 n...                  4                       COM12       
56  31/08/2019 21:33:57 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12       
57  31/08/2019 21:33:57 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
58  31/08/2019 21:33:57 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   4b 00 00 00                                                 K...                  4                       COM12       
59  31/08/2019 21:34:01 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      DOWN                                                                                                                             COM12       
60  31/08/2019 21:34:01 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   4b 00 00 00                                                 K...                  4                       COM12       
61  31/08/2019 21:34:04 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   55                                                          U                     1           1           COM12       
62  31/08/2019 21:34:04 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   55                                                          U                     1                       COM12       
63  31/08/2019 21:34:09 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
64  31/08/2019 21:34:09 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
65  31/08/2019 21:34:11 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
66  31/08/2019 21:34:11 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
67  31/08/2019 21:34:15 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            DOWN                   2e                                                          .                     1           1           COM12       
68  31/08/2019 21:34:15 IRP_MJ_WRITE                                            UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   2e                                                          .                     1                       COM12       
69  31/08/2019 21:34:21 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK)      DOWN                   00 00 00 00                                                 ....                  4                       COM12       
70  31/08/2019 21:34:21 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK)       UP    STATUS_SUCCESS   00 00 00 00                                                 ....                  4                       COM12       
71  31/08/2019 21:34:21 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK)      UP    STATUS_SUCCESS                                                                                                             COM12
```

[Dump file 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g22-CNliOI4sFqon6EfdgDC7INWcTrzy/view?usp=sharing)

[New Dump file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F80u5075dv3v1FT9lBTRvktpozyAukhc)

Comment: I tried to do this...... check after the read response..... but no response

Comment: Its tooo long that i couldnt upload here

Comment: i added some dump data

Comment: the dump file contains more text i couldnt post it here... how can i post the text file?

Comment: yes this is the communication between the device and the software..... its a long file but i posted a part of it..... i never worked like this devices.... thats why i have no idea how it works.... i know basic serial communication arduino to arduino... blutooth module... displays....

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post .... use TAB delimited data if you have an option when exporting the data dump

Comment: Sir i attached two file..... two from two different serial sniffer software

Comment: This depends on what data you need. The device seem to output a lot of information. You need to parse the string for the needed data. For example I found a line in the second dump file like `<SOH>Glucose [len=8]` followed by lines with glucose reading

Comment: yes.... iIn first file there is a tab called function... i can see that..... it uses some function to control it loke "IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW" and many more.... this is probably programing the serial device......

Comment: download Processing and use it to diagnose the communication protocol ( https://processing.org/download/ ) ... see the example serial port sketches ... the `new data.txt` file that you attached has promising information ... edit the file so that the timestamp is in left column ... `<20190901033932.479 SYS>   COM is open`
`<20190901033932.530 SYS>   Baud rate 1200` .... that will make it easier to follow

Comment: looks like you have to initiate the data exchange at 1200 baud and then switch to 9600 baud .... open port at 1200 baud, send `U` (0x55), close port ... open port at 1200 baud, send `<ENQ>` (0x05), close port .... open port at 9600 baud, send `<ENQ>` (0x05), data should start to be sent ..... if that works then try sending `U<ENQ>` together